# Sails Rest API using Passport-Facebook-Token Strategy Driving Me Nuts

Tags: facebook, api, rest, sails.js, facebook-access-token

I have a mobile front-end that already has facebook authetication working.  I have a Sails REST API that stores user data, posts etc..  I want to add security where facebook users can only POST GET DELETE PUT their own data.

I've read a almost every tutorial for facebook authenticating a web-app, but haven't found many for authenticating with a mobile app to protect the user data.  I've tried to get Passport-Facebook-Token working but I just don't understand the little documentation available. I'm coming from a objective-C background so in the node learning curve now.

Here's the link to what I'm working with but I'm obviously missing something:  https://github.com/drudge/passport-facebook-token

I have:

AuthController.js

```
module.exports = {
  facebook: function(req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('facebook-token', function(error, user, info) {
      // do stuff with user
      res.ok();
    })(req, res);
  }
};
```

api/services/protocols/passport.js
(with some other stuff from default passport sails-generate-auth)

```
var FacebookTokenStrategy = require('passport-facebook-token');

  passport.use('facebook-token', new FacebookTokenStrategy({
    clientID        : "<my_id>",
    clientSecret    : "<my_secret>"
  },

  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // console.log(profile);

    var user = {
        'email': profile.emails[0].value,
        'name' : profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName,
        'id'   : profile.id,
        'token': accessToken
    }

    // You can perform any necessary actions with your user at this point,
    // e.g. internal verification against a users table,
    // creating new user entries, etc.

    return done(null, user); // the user object we just made gets passed to the route's controller as `req.user`
  }
));
```

Do I have to do something with config/routes to make sure it only allows users with access_tokens?  I just can't find any resources out there.  Passport doesn't even list Passport-Facebook-Token strategy as an option on their site.

thank you for the help